# Error with WebFormsSearchDemo: "JsonData instance doesn't hold an int"

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-twitter

I'm using the WebFormsSearchDemo project. When I try doing a search it errors out with the following details:

```
JsonData instance doesn't hold an int  
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: JsonData instance doesn't hold an int

Source Error:


Line 27: select search;
Line 28:
Line 29: var searched = searchResults.First();
Line 30:
Line 31: SearchResultListView.DataSource = searched.Statuses;


Source File: c:\Users\Phill\Copy\Development\WebFormsDemos_2.1.07\WebFormsDemos\WebFormsSearchDemo\Results.aspx.cs Line: 29

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: JsonData instance doesn't hold an int]
LinqToTwitter.TwitterQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +763
System.Linq.Queryable.First(IQueryable`1 source) +251
WebFormsSearchDemo._Default.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Phill\Copy\Development\WebFormsDemos_2.1.07\WebFormsDemos\WebFormsSearchDemo\Results.aspx.cs:29
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9615682
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this may have been fixed by a newer version of LinqToTwitter, 2.1.10. See discussion here:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/463085

Comment: They havent released an updated WebFormsDemo for some time though so the issue hasnt been addressed in the demo files, and there is no indication as to how the files can be updated.